# Programmatic git fetch fails to ask for SSH key passphrase under Windows

Tags: git, ssh

I am writing a program to automate the process of ensuring several git repositories are up-to-date.  When I make a call to fetch remotes accessed via https, git prompts the user for a password or retrieves the password from whatever password manager the user has configured git to use.  This is good.

For repositories accessed via ssh, I am having difficulty explaining why git fails to ask for ssh key passphrases when called programmatically.  For example, when I do `$ git fetch --all` from the command line, I am prompted with something like `Enter passphrase for key 'xxxxx':`.  This is also true if I make this call from a batch file.

On Linux, I can write a C program that contains `system("git fetch --all")` and I get the same passphrase prompt.  But on Windows, this call results in `Permission denied (publickey)` without ever asking for the passphrase.

Any ideas?  The above is true with or without redirecting stdout and stderr, and I've tested that isatty() returns true when called in a program executed through a system() call.

Comment: Do you have a GIT_SSH environment variable set? What is it set to?

Comment: How do you run ssh under windows? Normally you'll need to have your private key loaded into an SSH authentication agent, such as pageant

Comment: @Kenster GIT_SSH is not set

Comment: @HBHB Ahha - I think you've got me pointed in the right direction.  When I said "everything works from the command line," I was using Git Bash, in which I've got ssh-agent set up with my private keys.  But using the Windows command prompt does NOT work.  That's got to be my issue.